# Sound Device Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: sound

How do I determine the correct selection in /dev/ for the sound card?
I installed gMFSK and the sound device dsp0 dsp1 dsp2 are not in the /dev directory.
The sound card is accessible by Rythmbox Music player and the sound does work  using  Sound System Settings.
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Install "alsa-oss"  (using this command `apt-get install alsa-oss` or software center).
Then , in a terminal , run this command :
`aoss gmfsk`
aoss make old OSS  only programs compatible with recent Alsa driver.

(I did not  test aoss with gmfsk , but it used to work fine with others programs )